# How do I insert a block quote within a paragraph using Pandoc?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I am using pandoc to convert from markdown to LaTeX. My problem is that Pandoc seems to interpret paragraph text following a block quote as the start of a new paragraph. While this is often what I want, there are many times that I want to continue the paragraph preceeding the quote. This is achieved easily enough in LaTeX---I simply insert the quote environment into the paragraph without leaving any blank lines between the quote and the surrounding lines, like this:

```
This is the first sentence of paragraph ONE.
\begin{quote}
This is a block quote.
\end{quote}
This is the second sentence of paragraph ONE.

This is the first sentence of paragraph TWO.
```

But since Pandoc requires block quotes be followed by a blank line, the only output I can manage looks like this:

```
This is the first sentence of paragraph ONE.

\begin{quote}
This is a block quote.
\end{quote}

This is the first sentence of paragraph TWO.

This is the first sentence of paragraph THREE.
```

How can I get pandoc to output LaTeX like my first example?

Comment: Is the main concern here an indentation of paragraph TWO?

Comment: Yes, if you're referring to the second example. In the pdf output, my aim is for the line immediately following the blockquote to NOT be indented. (An indented line indicates a new paragraph, which is not what I want.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LaTeX.

Answer (score 11):

After some searching I have found this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/multimarkdown/iIaBLYI92K0.

It seems unlikely that Pandoc's markdown is capable of distinguishing between continued and new paragraphs following block quotes. The best solution seems to use \noindent, like so:

```
This is the first sentence of paragraph ONE.

> This is a block quote.

\noindent This is the second sentence of paragraph ONE.

This is the first sentence of paragraph TWO.
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not mark the non-indented 'paragraph' as semantically joined to the first, so I imagine that any paragraph counter in LaTeX will still see three paragraphs here, not two.